# Invalid access to memory location when deploying Azure web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure web app that I'm deploying from VSTS. This was working fine previously but is now returning with the following:

> 2018-08-07T14:24:57.1655319Z Info: Adding directory (dsadminportal-dev\wwwroot\assets\css\plugins\datapicker).
>
> 2018-08-07T14:24:58.2654020Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
>
> 2018-08-07T14:24:58.2665943Z ##[error]
>   Error: (8/7/2018 2:24:57 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
>
> Error: An error was encountered when processing operation 'Create Directory' on 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\assets\css\plugins\datapicker'.
>   Error: The error code was 0x800703E6.
>   Error: Invalid access to memory location.
>
> at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.NativeMethods.RaiseIOExceptionFromErrorCode(Win32ErrorCode errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.FileSystemInfoEx.set_Attributes(FileAttributes value)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirPathProviderBase.Add(DeploymentObject source, Boolean whatIf)
>   Error count: 1.

This is to a slot. I deleted the slot and recreated it and it deployed fine first time but subsequent deploys fail with the above error.

Any ideas what this means?

Thanks

Comment: Strange. Probably some process run while you deploy there? Autoswap? Did you check Activity Log for that web site? Also you can skip dirs as per this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368655/msdeploy-and-skip-directories-not-named-x

Comment: The site is currently stopped during the deploy (I run a VSTS task to stop the slot). Don't think it can log if the site isn't running? I don't want to start skipping dirs till I know what the issue is

Comment: I am having a similar issue:

`2018-08-20T09:18:17.2950455Z Info: Updating file (App\.vs10x).
2018-08-20T09:18:19.0855891Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
2018-08-20T09:18:19.0868022Z ##[error]Error: (8/20/2018 10:18:17 AM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.`

Comment: I ran into the exactly the same issue when publishing an Azure Function from within Visual Studio and the accepted answer solved it for me.

Answer (score 66):

I found that as a workaround, publishing through the option "Run from ZIP" through the manual publishing dialog was working. But that option i think is not yet available from a VSTS task.

**Solution:**
I finally found out, that the workaround was actually causing the issue!
After deploying through ZIP, the function app setting WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE (formerly called WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_ZIP) was created. This was actually breaking deployment through web deploy!
Deleting the setting was fixing the issue.

see: https://azureappservices.blogspot.com/2018/08/409-conflict-could-not-write-to-local.html

Comment: Thanks, it helped! In the Azure Functions v2 this setting is called: "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE"

Comment: @PawelMaga Thanks for the hint. The name of the setting changed, so i updated the solution.

Comment: This only worked for me when I explicitly did not choose to deploy from package when clicking on Publish in VS in addition to deleting the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE setting (from application settings in the Azure portal).

Answer (score 6):

VSTS build is now with version 4 automatically "run from zip". Make sure you select web deploy in vsts, and remove any WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_ZIP in application settings. If it still doesn't work, recreate web service...

Answer (score 0):

Fix option: Open the same project using VS 2022 and publish again.

Problem: I was trying to publish on Azure using 2019, I started seeing 'Invalid memory location' out of nowhere, I checked for length of folders like some suggested, cleaned bin and obj folders, closed and re-open VS, reset computer and I got the same errors. Opening the project in VS 2022 did it for me, good luck.